# Managed custom action not working in Windows 8 without .NET 3.5 installed

Tags: windows-8, windows-installer, custom-action

in my Visual Studio 2010 setup project, I have a managed Custom Action.  It used to work great but will not on Windows 8 unless .NET 3.5 is installed.  I can't force my users to have .NET 3.5 installed - well I could, but I'd lose customers.

I have a vague understanding that maybe it's not working with .NET 4 because the shim DLL (installutillib.dll) has a dependency on .NET 2?

Is there anything I can do to get it to work?  I know managed CAs are frowned on by some, but need it to write a registry entry that depends on a bit of logic.

Thanks

Comment: A great reason to use InnoSetup: http://www.jrsoftware.org/  PS: Require .Net 3.5 to write a registry entry?  WTF?  There are a *million* ways to write the registry, and a million and 1 ways to script "custom action logic".  Consider InnoSetup, OK? ;)

Comment: Windows Installer has the Registry table.  Custom actions are not required and FWIW writing MSI's is not about "Scripting".  The exact opposite in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed CA's using installutillib.dll are frowned upon.  It's really bad stuff such as throwing modal 1001 error messages during silent/non-interactive installs, not supporting access to the MSI session, tattooing the MSIEXEC process with a CLR version (sticky) and many other horrible design shortcomings.

Use Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) managed custom actions instead.  It looks like a native custom action to the installer and has support for CustomAction.Config XML that expresses the SupportedRuntimes element.

[Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) Managed Custom Actions](http://blog.iswix.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-managed.html)

And of course, odds are you don't need custom actions to do what you are trying to do.  The Registry table supports [PROPERTY] expressions and the component it belongs to can use conditions to control installation or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'm digging into WiX.